# Excel data not sorting the type decimal.Decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, excel

I have a view where i export data the numerical data but when i sort the data it is not getting sorted as the excel is not considering the values as numerical data how can i convert them to numerical data in order to display the data in numerical format and make the sorting work.i have a function which gets the data here is how it looks.

```
    def get_output_value(self, key, value, neutral=None):
        display = value
        if value is None and not user.is_active:
            return '-', '-'

        if value is None:
            return f"${Decimal('.00')}", f"${Decimal('.00')}"

        if isinstance(value, Decimal):
            return f"${intcomma(value.quantize(Decimal('.00')))}",f"${intcomma(display.quantize(Decimal('.00')))}"

        return value, display


    def get_data(self):
            data = []

        for key in self.header_keys:
            value = getattr(neutral, str(key), '-')
            val, display = self.get_output_value(key, value, user)
            values_list.append({'value': val, 'display': display})
       

        data.append({'title': user.__str__(), 'value_row': values_list})

      return data
```

Comment: Where do you define thes `get_output_value`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it' s a mixin where i inherit in each type of list vieew where export data is required

Comment: Can you please share the mixin, or the library that you are using?

Comment: Sorry the mixin is 200 lines of code i think it's not possible but i am using Workbook() in BaseExportTask(Task)

Comment: and you don't have a gist or some repository or so? The problem is that you here return a string. I would use numerical values, and ensure that the item is set to "currency".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i have added some code can we format anything here?

Comment: no, you should include the code that eventually produces the xls, for example the code that interacts with the openpyxl package.

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap the data in float or int class types

e.g.

```
def get_output_value(self, key, value, neutral=None):
        display = value
        if value is None and not user.is_active:
            return 0, 0

        if value is None:
            return float(f"{Decimal('.00')}"), float(f"{Decimal('.00')}")

        if isinstance(value, Decimal):
            return float(f"{intcomma(value.quantize(Decimal('.00')))}"), float(f"{intcomma(display.quantize(Decimal('.00')))}")

        return float(value), display
```

**PROBABLY THE BETTER WAY:**

```
def get_output_value(self, key, value, neutral=None):
        display = value
        if value is None and not user.is_active:
            return 0, 0

        if value is None:
            return Decimal('.00'), Decimal('.00')

        if isinstance(value, Decimal):
            return intcomma(value.quantize(Decimal('.00'))), intcomma(display.quantize(Decimal('.00')))

        return float(value), display
```

Comment: **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$2,464.34'**

Comment: @Happy edited the answer removed the $ sign btw what is "Decimal" ? its not a python data type

Comment: ok I made a little bit of research the problem is that you are wrapping it inside the f string just remove the string, or my fix should be relevant too but not performance wise

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: we need dollar sign

Comment: Can we have the dollar sign make it work is there a way to like that?

Comment: add the dollar sign after sorting or just sort it as a string not decimal

Comment: i am not sorting here i sort it in the excel we just need to return the type of the value such that it gets sorted in excel

Comment: remove the $ sign and do this in excel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqpH5hLwljc remember to set values like this so formatting doesnt change => `ws["A1"].value = 10.21`

Comment: if it's for self i could have done that but they need with the $ sign and work in general

Comment: its bad practice to have currency as string idk